# capturing spike with sharp rise and fall due to noise in data

Tags: statistics, data-science

A picture would have explain the problem I have better. I try smoothing and take the difference between the predicted value and the actual value. It does not get the points I want. y is the number of errors in logs and x is time. The system does not output errors in regular intervals. e.g. 5 errors at time t, 0 errors at time t+1, 10 errors at time t+2, 11 errors at time t+3, 2 errors at time t+4.

I want to pick out the points where errors are dropping in general as indicated in the graph.

I think about creating a windows and measuring the gradient like my boss suggests initially but I think the 0 errors in between do not seem to easy for the gradient approach either.  Any good idea?

[image]